# How to find the version of JSSE used in a specific JDK version?

Tags: ssl, java

I'm running jdk 1.6.0_24 in a custom linux OS based system.  I've received questions from a client's auditor around the version of SSL is on GUI and what is driving it in the backend.  I know that we're using JSSE within JDK to do SSL, but I can't seem to find JSSE version.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually can answer this one myself... dunno why I didn't think of it sooner.  Ran strings against /path/to/jdkstuff/blah/jsse.jar and got this at the top:

```
META-INF/PK
META-INF/MANIFEST.MFManifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
Implementation-Version: 1.6
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.sun
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
Created-By: 1.6.0_18-ea (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Specification-Version: 1.6
```

Looks like it'll be enough for audit purposes :)

Comment: Aaaand. It tells you 1.6 which is not more that the JDK/JRE version.

Comment: Indeed, but when I told them the JDK version they weren't happy enough, showing them this was satisfactory... probably looking out for the possibility I'd be using a newer JDK with a drop in JSSE.jar that was older?  Who knows, point is, I did what I could, and they're satisfied now :)

Comment: Funny auditors. It's always fun to work with them. :)

Answer (score 1):

As it is in the JDK/JRE itself I would answer 1.6.0_24. But if the auditor asks for the SSL and TLS version, it is SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0.

More documentation can be found at [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html).

Comment: Yeah, I got the SSL/TLS version by using openssl s_client -connect (etc)... but the auditor wants to know what's running it on the server.  Thanks though